# Unable to connect local scala app with Hbase running in docker

Tags: docker, scala, apache-spark, hbase

I have spent the entire day trying to figure out why my sscala app running on windows is unable to make a successful connection with hbase running in a docker container.
I can shell into the container and run the hbase shell, create tables etc
Also I can port forward to localhost:16010 and see the Hbase UI. Some additional details of the setup as follows.

Env:
Scala app: Windows (host)

Hbase: docker container

Docker container details

```
FROM openjdk:8

ENV HBASE_VERSION=2.4.12

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y netcat

RUN mkdir -p /var/hbase && \
    cd /opt && \
    wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/hbase/${HBASE_VERSION}/hbase-${HBASE_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf hbase-${HBASE_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz

WORKDIR /opt/hbase-${HBASE_VERSION}

COPY hbase-site.xml conf

CMD ./bin/start-hbase.sh && tail -F logs/hbase*.log
```

hbase-site.xml -> hbase.cluster.distributed & hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce set to false

The hbase container is up and running and accesible. Also confirmed zookeeper is reachable within the container as well as from the host using `echo ruok | nc localhost 2181; echo`

Running container as follows:
`docker run -it -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 -p 16010:16010 -p 16000:16000 -p 16020:16020 -p 16030:16030 -p 8080:8080 -h hbb hbase-1`

Scala app

```
  val conf : Configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create()
  conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "hbb")
  conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
  conf.set("hbase.master", "hbb")
  conf.set("hbase.cluster.distributed","false")
  // conf.set("hbase.client.pause", "1000")
  // conf.set("hbase.client.retries.number", "2")
  // conf.set("zookeeper.recovery.retry", "1")
  val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf)
```

The part of the stack trace

```
1043 [ReadOnlyZKClient-hbb:2181@0x30b6ffe0] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - zookeeper.disableAutoWatchReset is false
3947 [ReadOnlyZKClient-hbb:2181@0x30b6ffe0-SendThread(hbb:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Opening socket connection to server hbb:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
3949 [ReadOnlyZKClient-hbb:2181@0x30b6ffe0-SendThread(hbb:2181)] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Session 0x0 for server hbb:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:100)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:620)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.registerAndConnect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:277)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.connect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:287)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1021)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1064)
3953 [ReadOnlyZKClient-hbb:2181@0x30b6ffe0-SendThread(hbb:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO  - Ignoring exception during shutdown input
java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateToSocketException(Net.java:122)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateException(Net.java:156)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateException(Net.java:162)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.shutdownInput(SocketAdaptor.java:401)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.cleanup(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:200)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.cleanup(ClientCnxn.java:1250)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1174)
```

I have tried changing the `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` & `master` props on the client side to localhost / 127.0.0.1 as well as changing the etc/hosts file with the container id. No luck yet

Would greatly appreciate some guidance on this :)

Comment: Where does the Scala app runs? On the host directly? In a container?

Comment: Hey Gael, the Scala app runs on the host directly..